# Supremum of a function is its limits?

Tags: limits, supremum-and-infimum

we learned about limit at infinity, after we studied about supremum and infimum last month, and I thought about something I'm struggling to think whether it's true or not.

If I know that a function has a supremum, is it always true that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)=sup(f(x))$?

Say$\ f(x)<1$ for every $\ x\geq$ 0, and I am given that$\ sup(f(x))=1$, does it mean that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)=1$?

Comment: No, this is not true. For example, consider the function $\frac{\sin x}x$. It is obvious that the supremum of this function is $>0$, but the limit is $0$.

Comment: As mentioned by others, it’s not true in general. However, have you considered the case it $f$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above? This would lead to is quite a standard result that might be worth exploring if you’ve not seen it already. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take, for instance$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,\infty)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\dfrac{x\sin x}{x+1}.\end{array}$$Then $\sup\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=1$, but the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ doesn't exist.

[image]

Comment: But if, for example, there is a function such that $\ f(x)<1$ for every $\ x\geq$ 0, and $\ sup(f(x))=1$, does it mean that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)=1$?

Comment: No, as my example shows.